# Replacing contents of HTML canvas with Springy force-directed graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a nice force-directed graph using the [Springy](http://getspringy.com/) force-directed graph layout library. I've discovered that when I replace the graph with another via ajax (e.g., after the user has changed some settings), both graphs occupy the same canvas.

**What I'm looking for:** I need to get rid of the old graph completely, so the new graph is the only one present in the canvas.

Here's a simplified usecase jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/XPAqX/

```
// make a new graph
var graph = new Springy.Graph();

// make some nodes
var spruce = graph.newNode({label: 'Norway Spruce'});
var fir = graph.newNode({label: 'Sicilian Fir'});

// connect them with an edge
graph.newEdge(spruce, fir);


$('#my_canvas').springy({ graph: graph, nodeSelected: function(node) {
    alert(node.data.label);
} });

//now, I let the user update the dataset with ajax and re-render the graph. 

graph = null;
graph = new Springy.Graph();



// make some nodes
var kittens = graph.newNode({label: 'Furry Baby Cats'});
var puppies = graph.newNode({label: 'Fluffy Baby Dogs'});

// connect them with an edge
graph.newEdge(kittens,puppies);


$('#my_canvas').springy({ graph: graph });
```

Quick note: cross-posted as an issue on the springy github, no answers yet though: https://github.com/dhotson/springy/issues/47

Comment: so what do u want ?? should they both use diff canvas ??

Comment: Ah, guess it wasn't clear enough. I want ONLY ONE graph in the canvas, so the new one exists and the old one doesn't. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: i am not familiar with this script, but can you check if it has a clear/destroy/redraw method? If it has you can destroy the older canvas data and re-create your canvas with your new data from your ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Springy Graph object is a little misleading. If you check out the sources you'll see it's just a access layer over the whole Springy context object (a signleton) that actually holds your nodes, so `addNode` does not add nodes to the Graph object but to a singleton Springy context object.

You'll have to use `removeNode` to remove the old nodes first, like I did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XPAqX/1/).

Just to make things clearer:
Yes, Graph objects do contain lists of nodes, but those are passed to the renderer, and the renderer is a single instance for each canvas DOM node you 'springyfy'. Changing the Graph instance won't reset the renderer's internal context.

A more complicated solution would be to modify the [SpringyUI](https://github.com/dhotson/springy/blob/master/springyui.js) (jQuery plugin) code and handle a $('#canvas').springy('reset') method that resets the internal renderer. Looking at the SpringyUI code I can say that won't be easy.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it's useful. A shame there's no easy way to just clear it all - I might consider trying to write something for springyui and sharing it in the future as I think it could come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

edit: (deleted all the wrong stuff of me)

to get a working solution:

add one of the following clear function to the springyui.js

```
this.clear = function(){
   for(var i=graph.nodes.length-1;i>=0;i--){
     graph.removeNode(graph.nodes[i]);
   }
}
```

or

```
this.clear = function(){
    graph.nodeSet = {};
    graph.nodes = [];
    graph.edges = [];
    graph.adjacency = {};
    graph.notify();
}
```

use it like this:

initial:

```
//don't call this twice!!
var graph = new Springy.Graph();
var springy=jQuery('#yourcanvas').springy({graph: graph});
```

workflow:

```
function makeGraph(){
    springy.clear();
    //generate your graph hear
    graph.addNodes(...)
}
```